# Securing snippet with dropping eval() in input-file parsing

Tags: php, parsing, eval, php-5.3

I have a template-esque system which can load *bulk templates* (more than one template entry in one file) and store them accordingly. The problem is that the current approach uses `preg_replace()` and `eval` and it is really error-prone. An example for this error could be an improperly-placed character which breaks the regular expression and creates a parse error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in tsys.php: eval()'d code
```

The code which does this said loading is the following:

```
// Escaping
$this->_buffer = str_replace( array('\\', '\'', "\n"), array('\\\\', '\\\'', ''), $this->_buffer);

// Regular-expression chunk up the input string to evaluative code
$this->_buffer = preg_replace('#<!--- BEGIN (.*?) -->(.*?)<!--- END (.*?) -->#', "\n" . '$this->_tstack[\'\\1\'] = \'\\2\';', $this->_buffer);

// Run the previously created PHP code
eval($this->_buffer);
```

An example file of this *bulk template* looks like the following:

```
<!--- BEGIN foo -->
<p>Some HTML code</p>
<!--- END foo -->

<!--- BEGIN bar -->
<h1>Some other HTML code</h1>
<!--- END bar -->
```

When the code is ran on this input, the `$this->_tstack` will be given two elements:

```
array (
  'foo' => "<p>Some HTML code</p>",
  'bar' => "<h1>Some other HTML code</h1>",
);
```

Which is the expected behavior but I am looking for a method which we could drop the need of `eval`.

Comment: WTF is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: @ircmaxell You store the HTML in these files, and this code is supposed to load these files into the internal `_tstack` container, from which, you can print templates to the screen. What I am searching an approach for parsing multi- (or bulk-) template files without the need of `eval()`.

Comment: @ircmaxell And for a greater insight: after the template is loaded, you can `prepare` templates (templates can have _variable places_ inside them which are filled with values), add them to output buffers and if needed, print them on the screen. Templates are the ones who contain what HTML the system should and will output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here goes. Given `$template` contains:

```
<!--- BEGIN foo -->
    <p>Some HTML code</p>
<!--- END foo -->

<!--- BEGIN bar -->
    <h1>Some other HTML code</h1>
<!--- END bar -->
```

Then:

```
$values = array();
$pattern = '#<!--- BEGIN (?P<key>\S+) -->(?P<value>.+?)<!--- END (?P=key) -->#si';
if ( preg_match_all($pattern, $template, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $values[$match['key']] = trim($match['value']);
    }
}
var_dump($values);
```

Results in:

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(21) "<p>Some HTML code</p>"
  ["bar"]=>
  string(29) "<h1>Some other HTML code</h1>"
}
```

*If white space preservation is important, remove `trim()`.*

Comment: This did work, with some slight modifications. Because template names can contain whitespaces, I needed to change `(?P<key>\S+)` to `(?P<key>\S.+)`. I have altered the answer to make it look like a valid PHP code, because there were some syntax errors. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Whisperity Sorry, that was valid PHP 5.4 code; not 5.3. Your edits make it backward compatible; thank you :) Also, it's probably best to narrow the character class allowance to what you need. If it can only be whitespace and "word characters" (*letters, digits, and underscores*), then `[\w\s]+` should suffice. `[\w\s-]+` for hyphens too.

Comment: I have just updated to PHP `5.4.4`, but when I tested the code I only had `5.3.8`. Off topic, but should I try to make it (the project) backward compatible, or drop it all, and write it as a new code?

Comment: @Whisperity That depends on far too many factors. Backward compatibility is obviously a massive asset (*read; necessity*) for libraries/applications made publicly available for use in the wild. However, if this is purely an in-house solution, I would leverage features offered by the latest release, and start coding new. Again, too many other factors; you'll have to decide for yourself.

Comment: @Bracketwroks I think I won't fudge on `[]` instead of `array()`, but will drop `mysql_` in favour of `mysqli_`. Anyway, before we go more off-topic, I wish to thank you for the solution. I really need to learn RegExp more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match_all` to do that:

```
// Remove CR and NL
$buffer = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $this->_buffer);

// Grab interesting parts
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\?\?\? BOT (?P<group>[^ ]+) \?\?\?(?P<content>.*)!!! EOT \1 !!!/', $buffer, $matches);

// Build the stack
$stack = array_combine(array_values($matches['group']), array_values($matches['content']));
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => <p>Some HTML code</p>
    [bar] => <h1>Some other HTML code</h1>
)
```

Comment: The method did work, but since I asked, the templates were modified to use a different, more HTML-like format (see the updated question). And I am not sure how to modify your `preg_replace_all()` line to prevent the system from getting `Warning: array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have at least 1 element` error and `FALSE` as `$stack`.